# Retrofit 2 doesn't work on android 10 (api 29)

Tags: android, retrofit

I write some retrofit code and I run on API 29 emulator but it didn't work. Without any error or any log message. But it runs well on my android phone (android 8 ) and API 27 emulator. I search all web but didn't find anything. can you figure out why this happened
This is my code for Retrofit part:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .build()

    val retrofit : Retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://www.flickr.com/")
        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
    val flickrApi = retrofit.create(FlickrApi::class.java)
    val flickrHomePageRequest = flickrApi.fetchContents()



    flickrHomePageRequest.enqueue(object : Callback<String> {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call<String>, response: Response<String>) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Response received ${response.body()}")
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<String>, t: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Failed to fetch photos",t)

        }

    })
    
}
```

I also tried network security config and clear text traffic but none of them worked.

This is my xml code :

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">flickr.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

And finally this is my retrofit api interface

```
interface FlickrApi {

    @GET("/")
    fun fetchContents():Call<String>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add below code to your manifest :

```
<application
    ...
      android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...
</application>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use android 9 (Pie) or android SDK above 28 and get the issue on over the api call through Retrofit.

Add this line to your manifest

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```